# Why the status of my G Suite Marketplace app always displays: GAM: pending?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have published my G Suite Marketplace app for the better part of a month, but the status is always "GAM: pending" and there is no one who told me if there is something wrong with my app and I do't know what should I do for this situation?

Comment: I think you need to [open an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191597&template=823910) and report your situation. You can also reach out on the Chrome team [here](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support)

Answer (score 1):

The same thing is happening to me. When I reached out to Add-on Support they replied with the following:

> The “GAM pending” status shown in the CWS developer dashboard is an
>   expected behaviour and is an old status that will be changed once the
>   CWS migration completed.